# How to get start tag & end tag of an HTML element using PHP

Tags: php, html

I was trying whole day to implement this, but there isn't any progress.

I have this part of code

```
 $LookUpData =array(
        ID1 =>  '<div> First </div>',
        ID2 => '<p>Second</p>'
    );

$tagData = $LookUpData[ID1];
print_r($tagData);
```

The output that I got in this case is: 
First

Ideal scenario will be if I will get:

```
           0 => <div>
           1 => First
           2 => </div>
```

I hope that you understand what is my problem and what I need. Every kind of help is welcome.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to extract? The innerHTML and the tags separately?

Comment: cant get u??u want the second output??

Comment: Look into an HTML DOM parser, such as [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I need start_tag, text between the tags, end_tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that solves your problem

```
<?php
$LookUpData =array(
        'ID1' =>  '<div> First </div>',
        'ID2' => '<p>Second</p>'
);

$tagData = $LookUpData['ID1'];

preg_match('#(<.*?>)(.*)(</.*?>)#', $LookUpData['ID1'],$m);
unset($m[0]);
print_r($m);
?>
```

The output from code:

```
 Array ( [1] => <div> [2] => First [3] => </div> )
```

Explanation:

- You should use '' or "" when you want to name keys for arrays. If you won't do it you will get notice that it is not constant
- Preg match perfectly fits your needs because it's look for pattern match in string.

Pattern explanation:

- `##` - are characters that define begin and end of pattern
- `(<.*?>)` - is subpattern that will look for any character between <> it will fit

  etc.
- `(.*)` - this is pattern for any character(almost any)
- `(</.*?>)` - another subpattern this time for closing tag almost the same as the first one.

[Online demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/72n-ivm) - notice that code is a bit different to be properly displayed in browser(html tags)

Comment: Just one more question. What if I have a situation like: <p id="test"> Some text </p> and I need identical output like in the above solution. 
First element in array needs to be <p> not <p id="test">. 

Question is how to remove everything after whitespace in a start tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/(<[^>]+>)(.*)(<\/[^>]>)/", "<div>First</div>", $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Should be enough to get you started

Comment: It doesn't work. I just tested it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

$LookUpData =array(
        ID1 =>  '<div> First </div>',
        ID2 => '<p>Second</p>'
    );

$tagData = $LookUpData[ID1];


$matches = array();
preg_match("/(<[^>]>)(.*)(<\/[^>]>)/", "<div>First</div>", $matches);
var_dump($matches);

Comment: There are some mistakes in it `[^>]` fits only 1 character you should ad `*?` or `+?` to these classes. Also `.*` is greedy which is not good for large html file.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to quantify [^>]